# Enable ping in Windows 7 firewall?

Tags: windows-7, firewall, ping

[Server Fault tells](https://serverfault.com/questions/6046/enable-ping-in-windows-server-firewall) that the new syntax to enable ping on Windows Server 2008 is

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request"
    protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow
```

but this doesn't work with Windows 7. Here I get

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow

A specified value is not valid.

Usage: add rule name=<string>
...
```

What is the correct new syntax?

Comment: You could try adding it through the GUI?  Control Panel --> System and security --> Windows Firewall --> Advanced settings --> Inbound rules --> New rule --> custom rule

Comment: Windows ships with a firewall rule for that, btw. Confusingly, it’s in the File and Printer Sharing category. Its name depends on your OS language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is copy and paste. With the right quotation marks

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request"
    protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow
```

does the job. I'm not sure from which source I copied the problematic version.

Comment: A number of blogging and content platforms have misguided "smart" quotes that mess up all kinds of code fragments.

Answer (score 3):

*Control Panel* --> *System and Security* --> *Windows Firewall* --> *Advanced settings* --> right click on *Inbound rules* --> *New rule* --> *Custom rule* -> *Next*

In *Protocol and ports* (chosen in the left panel): *Protocol: ICMPv4*

In the same panel, press button *Customize*, choose "Specific ICMP types", check the box "Echo Request", and press button *OK*.

In *Name* (chosen in the left panel): fill in the Name field and press *Apply*.

Comment: This worked when I tried it.

Comment: On Windows 10, hit the Windows key, type "fire", and chose *"Windows Firewall"*. On the last screen the button to use is *"Finish"* instead of *"Apply"* (as it does not exist). It starts working immediately (no restart, etc. needed).

Comment: Or for later versions of Windows 10: Windows key, type "firew", and chose *"Windows Defender Firewall"*.

Answer (score 3):

When I typed:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Enable Echo Ping Request" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow
```

into my Windows PowerShell ISE, I got an error: "A specified protocol value is not valid."

I fixed it by using this:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Enable Echo Ping Request" protocol="icmpv4:8,any" dir=in action=allow
```

Comment: Note that your fix is specific to Powershell (you need to protect the `,`), it won't happen if you were using the traditional CMD command line as did the OP.