# Enable ping in Windows Server for specific IP addresses only?

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, ping

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/342822/enable-ping-in-windows-7-firewall) was solved by a user saying how to enable ping but in a general way - For everybody.

Command showed here is:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request"
    protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow
```

But what i want to achieve is to enable icmp request from a single IP address only (Which is another server)

How do i do that?
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You already pointed yourself in the right direction. What does your research show?

Comment: What? No. The question above does not work for specific address... It enables ICMP ping for ALL ip adresses. My question is: "How do i enable ICMP ping ONLY for ONE SINGLE address."

Comment: I don't want to enable ICMP for everybody. I just want to allow ICMP requests from a single IP Address only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the `netsh advfirewall` command the following parameter:

```
remoteip=IPAddress
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked... I did the same command but with flag remoteip=192.168.xxx and thats exactly what i needed!